# What images published in arXiv papers can I include in my education material?

Tags: arxiv, graphics, license

I am going to give a course at my company and I'm looking online for images that I can use in my education material.

Since many of the most interesting images suitable for this education exist in papers published on arXiv, how do I know which of the images found in arXiv papers I can use and which I can't? How do I know how these images are licenced?

I often see images published in arXiv papers that are later used in presentations given by other people and/or republished in other's research papers, sometimes without any credit given to the creators of the images and almost always without a link to any license (in fact I can't remember ever seeing such a link, but maybe I have just not paid attention). Under what circumstances is that okay?

A related question is, how does fair use come into all of this since we're talking about education material?

Comment: if you don't publish your course materials you can certainly do anything you want with images from there. in case you publish, you would need to provide appropriate references to these images, and it might also be the case that your publication would  need a similar copyright.

Comment: What does it mean to "publish"  the material? If I hand it out to the course participants as printed copies, or if I email it to them as a PDF, does that count as publishing?

Comment: no, this is not publishing.

Comment: Treat them like you would any other published materials, considering copyright and licensing, as well as the intended use. If there is any doubt, ask.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Theft is theft, regardless of whether it committed in public

Comment: @user2768 More relevant to the question here, copyright infringement is copyright infringement, whether public or not.

Comment: @TommiBrander Isn't copyright infringement theft?

Comment: @user2768 It is contested; you can find both takes on the matter by checking for example Torrentfreak and any copyright lobby. Maybe start with Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement#%22Theft%22. (I do not think it is theft, as you are not taking anything away. You are making copies you are not supposed to make. Contrast with theft, where something is taken away.)

Comment: @user2728 if you can print a copy of a paper from arxiv.org ( and yes, you can, check licences there) then you can print 20 copies and give them to your students.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik, how about 2000 copies? 200,000? And "giving them away" is a bit different from printing a copy for your own use.

Comment: there are limits to what "fair use" is, I agree. But in the context of a corporate lecture series, or university teaching,  I don't see a problem. I can just as well tell students: here is the URL, print it out yourselves.

Comment: charging for these copies (beyond printing costs) would not be legal, I gather.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to the other answer, arXiv does not require that papers are posted under CC licences. The minimal (and normal) licence required is given [here](https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html), and merely grants arXiv perpetual right to distribute the article. IANAL but I very much doubt this gives you any right to use individual figures.

You can find a (small) link to the licence for a particular preprint on the right-hand side of the abstract page in arXiv. You should see something like

[image]

If there is a CC licence you can use the image but probably need to attribute. Otherwise, I would contact the authors to ask for permission.

Answer (score 4):

You should check the licence under which the paper is posted on arXiv. It requires that papers are posted under creative commons licences which means you will always be able to use the content, but whether you are obliged to attribute the source depends on the flavour of license. More information here

https://arxiv.org/help/license

Personally, I would always be inclined to attribute figures where I take them from others, under the idea of 'treat others as you would like to be treated'.

Comment: Arxiv does not require Creative commons.